# With Elmish.wpf/F#, how to display in WPF a string option as the string or null, not "Some(string)"?

Tags: f#, elmish-wpf

I am a newbie to F#. In WPF, I am using DisplayMemberBinding within a Datagrid as:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <local:AppointmentListView ItemsSource="{Binding Columns[0].AppointmentKeys}" Height="140" Background="Bisque">
                                    <ListView.View>
                                        <GridView>
                                            <GridViewColumn Header="First"     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}" Width="100"/>
                                            <GridViewColumn Header="Last"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding LastName}"  Width="120"/>
                                            <GridViewColumn Header="BirthDate" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding BirthDate, StringFormat=d}" Width="100"/>
                                        </GridView>
                                    </ListView.View>
                                </local:AppointmentListView>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The (complete) backing F# module (in Elmish.wpf) is:

```
module MyDataGrid.DataGrid

open Elmish
open Elmish.WPF
open System

type Visit = 
    {   ServiceTime: DateTime option
        DoNotSee: Boolean option
        ChartNumber: int option
        LastName: string option
        FirstName: string option
        Mi: string option
        BirthDate: DateTime option
        PostingTime: DateTime option 
        AppointmentTime: DateTime option }

type Cell = 
  {RowNumber: int
   ColumnNumber: int
   AppointmentKeys: Visit list
   ColumnTime: TimeSpan
   AppointmentCount: int
   AppointmentTime: DateTime option  // all lines in the cell have the same appointment time.     
  }

let SetCell (rowNumber: int, columnNumber: int) =
    let AppointmentsPerCell = 4
    {RowNumber = rowNumber
     ColumnNumber = columnNumber
     AppointmentKeys = [for x in 1 .. AppointmentsPerCell -> 
                           {
                             ServiceTime = Some System.DateTime.Now 
                             DoNotSee = Some false 
                             ChartNumber = Some 8812 
                             LastName= Some ("LastName" + string x)
                             FirstName= Some ("FirstName" + string x)
                             Mi = Some "J" 
                             BirthDate = Some(DateTime(2020,09,14))
                             PostingTime = Some DateTime.Now
                             AppointmentTime = Some DateTime.Now
                         }]      
     ColumnTime = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(float(columnNumber * 15))
     AppointmentCount = 4
     AppointmentTime = Some(DateTime.Now)
     }

type Row =
  {RowTime: string
   Columns: Cell list}

let SetRow (rowNumber: int, startTime: System.TimeSpan)= 
    let columnCount = 4
    let hr = System.TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0)
    let rowTime = startTime + System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(hr.Ticks * int64(rowNumber))
    { RowTime = rowTime.ToString("h':00'")
      Columns = [for columnNumber in 1 .. columnCount -> SetCell(rowNumber, columnNumber) ]
    }

type Model =
  { AppointmentDate: DateTime
    Rows: Row list
    SelectedRow: Row option}

type Msg =
  | SetAppointmentDate of DateTime
  | SetSelectedRow of Row option

let init =
      let rowCount = 9
      let startTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(float(8))
      { AppointmentDate = DateTime.Now 
        Rows = [for rowNumber in 0 .. rowCount -> SetRow(rowNumber, startTime)]
        SelectedRow = None
      }

let update msg m =
  match msg with
  | SetAppointmentDate d -> {m with AppointmentDate = d}
  | SetSelectedRow r -> {m with SelectedRow = r}

let bindings () : Binding<Model, Msg> list = [
  "SelectedAppointmentDate" |> Binding.twoWay( (fun m -> m.AppointmentDate), SetAppointmentDate)
  "Rows" |> Binding.oneWay( fun m -> m.Rows)
  "SelectedRow" |> Binding.twoWay( (fun m -> m.SelectedRow), SetSelectedRow)
]

let designVm = ViewModel.designInstance init (bindings ())


let main window =
  Program.mkSimpleWpf (fun () -> init) update bindings
  |> Program.withConsoleTrace
  |> Program.runWindowWithConfig
    { ElmConfig.Default with LogConsole = true; Measure = true }
    window
```

The DisplayMememberBindings show LastName as "Some(LastName1)" and BirthDate as "Some(09/14/2020 00:00:00)".

**How can I get the  LastName: string option to return either null or the value of the string so the display shows "LastName1" and not "Some(LastName1)?**

The same goes for the birth date, how to show BirthDate as "9/14/2020" and not "Some(09/14/2020 00:00:00)?

TIA

Full source code at: [Example DataGrid](https://github.com/awaynemd/MyDataGrid)

Comment: Too simple for an answer but... `Option.defaultValue ""` will do the trick

Comment: Cross posed at https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/issues/280

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code only has three bindings.  You should have a binding for every individual piece of data.  Specifically, you should change your `Rows` binding from a `OneWay` binding to a `SubModel` binding.  Then repeat this for all your other types.

Then, the question you specifically asked about is how to display `LastName1` instead of `Some(LastName1)` and `9/14/2020` instead of `Some(09/14/2020 00:00:00)`.  Create the bindings for these individual pieces of optional data with `Binding` methods that ends in `Opt` like [`Binding.oneWayOpt`](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/bd74fd68dcc5cdbf12f98341c76945c663d837bf/src/Elmish.WPF/Binding.fs#L319-L346) or [`Binding.twoWayOpt`](https://github.com/elmish/Elmish.WPF/blob/bd74fd68dcc5cdbf12f98341c76945c663d837bf/src/Elmish.WPF/Binding.fs#L522-L565).

Comment: I did the best I could--and completely failed.  How do you create a submodel of a "row list"?  Please see source code at:  https://github.com/awaynemd/DatagridWithSubModel    Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

For newbies like me, here is *my* full F# *working* solution in Elmish.WPF/F#:

```
module MyDataGrid.DataGrid

open Elmish
open Elmish.WPF
open System

module Visit = 
    
    type Model =
       { ServiceTime: DateTime option
         DoNotSee: Boolean option
         ChartNumber: int option
         LastName: string option
         FirstName: string option
         Mi: string option
         BirthDate: DateTime option
         PostingTime: DateTime option 
         AppointmentTime: DateTime option 
         Id: int}

    let SetVisits appointmentsPerCell  = [for x in 1 .. appointmentsPerCell -> 
                                                {
                                                  ServiceTime = Some System.DateTime.Now 
                                                  DoNotSee = Some false 
                                                  ChartNumber = Some 8812 
                                                  LastName= Some ("LastName" + string x)
                                                  FirstName= Some ("FirstName" + string x)
                                                  Mi = Some "J" 
                                                  BirthDate = Some(DateTime(2020,09,14))
                                                  PostingTime = Some DateTime.Now
                                                  AppointmentTime = Some DateTime.Now
                                                  Id = x
                                              }]   
    
    let bindings() = [
        "FirstName" |> Binding.oneWayOpt( fun (_, m) -> m.FirstName)
        "LastName"  |> Binding.oneWayOpt( fun (_, m) -> m.LastName)
        "BirthDate" |> Binding.oneWayOpt( fun (_, m) -> m.BirthDate) 
        "ServiceTime" |> Binding.oneWayOpt( fun (_, m) -> m.ServiceTime)
    ]

module Cell =

    type Model =
        { RowNumber: int
          ColumnNumber: int
          AppointmentKeys: Visit.Model list
          ColumnTime: TimeSpan
          AppointmentCount: int
          AppointmentTime: DateTime option  // all lines in the cell have the same appointment time.  
          Id: int
        }

    let SetCell (rowNumber: int, columnNumber: int) =
        let AppointmentsPerCell = 4
        {RowNumber = rowNumber
         ColumnNumber = columnNumber
         AppointmentKeys =  Visit.SetVisits AppointmentsPerCell  
         ColumnTime = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(float(columnNumber * 15))
         AppointmentCount = 4
         AppointmentTime = Some(DateTime.Now)
         Id=rowNumber*10 + columnNumber
         }

    let bindings() =[
        "AppointmentKeys"  |> Binding.subModelSeq(
                                (fun (_, m) -> m.AppointmentKeys),
                                (fun v -> v.Id),
                                 Visit.bindings                            
                              )
    ]

module Row =

    type Model =
      { RowTime: string
        Columns: Cell.Model list 
        Id: int }

    let SetRow (rowNumber: int, startTime: System.TimeSpan)= 
        let columnCount = 4
        let hr = System.TimeSpan.FromHours(1.0)
        let rowTime = startTime + System.TimeSpan.FromTicks(hr.Ticks * int64(rowNumber))
        { RowTime = rowTime.ToString("h':00'")
          Columns = [for columnNumber in 1 .. columnCount -> Cell.SetCell(rowNumber, columnNumber) ]
          Id = rowNumber
        }

    
    let bindings () = [
        "RowTime" |> Binding.oneWay( fun (_,r) -> r.RowTime)
        "Columns" |> Binding.subModelSeq(
                                            (fun (_, m) -> m.Columns),
                                            (fun c -> c.Id),
                                             Cell.bindings                            
                                          )
    
    ] 
    

type Model =
  { AppointmentDate: DateTime
    Rows: Row.Model list
    SelectedRow: Row.Model option}

type Msg =
  | SetAppointmentDate of DateTime
  | SetSelectedRow of Row.Model option

let init () =
    let rowCount = 9
    let startTime = TimeSpan.FromHours(float(8))
    { AppointmentDate = DateTime.Now 
      Rows = [for rowNumber in 0 .. rowCount -> Row.SetRow(rowNumber, startTime)]
      SelectedRow = None
    }

let update msg m =
  match msg with
  | SetAppointmentDate d -> {m with AppointmentDate = d}
  | SetSelectedRow r -> {m with SelectedRow = r}

let bindings () : Binding<Model, Msg> list = [
  "SelectedAppointmentDate" |> Binding.twoWay( (fun m -> m.AppointmentDate), SetAppointmentDate)
  "Rows" |> Binding.subModelSeq(
                                 (fun m -> m.Rows),
                                 (fun r -> r.Id),
                                  Row.bindings                          
                               )
  "SelectedRow" |> Binding.twoWay( (fun m -> m.SelectedRow), SetSelectedRow)
]

let main window =
  Program.mkSimpleWpf init update bindings
  |> Program.withConsoleTrace
  |> Program.runWindowWithConfig
    { ElmConfig.Default with LogConsole = true; Measure = true }
    window
    enter code here
```